# get value from json and set to select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

Check my JQ code bellow. I have a json data like in `data` variable. And i want to loop though all of data and set value in html like example html. Can u help me to fix that? Thanks in advance

Html:

```
<select name="mainMenuSelect" id="mainMenuSelect">
    <option value="MainMenuId">MenuName</option> //this output is my target
</select>
```

Jquery code:

```
var data = '{"MainMenuId":6,"MenuName":"T-Shairt","StoreId":1,"Store":null},{"MainMenuId":7,"MenuName":"Pants","StoreId":1,"Store":null},{"MainMenuId":9,"MenuName":"unixx","StoreId":1,"Store":null},{"MainMenuId":10,"MenuName":"things","StoreId":1,"Store":null}';

$.each(data, function (key, value) {
    $('#mainMenuSelect').append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>');
});
```

Comment: Well you're not parsing the JSON into an enumerable object before attempting to iterate over it. Always check the erorr console.

Comment: Oh i see. Can u answer the implementation in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON format is invalid. Here is the working code

```html
<select name="mainMenuSelect" id="mainMenuSelect">
    <option value="MainMenuId">MenuName</option>
</select>

<script>
  var data = [{"MainMenuId":6,"MenuName":"T-Shairt","StoreId":1,"Store":null},{"MainMenuId":7,"MenuName":"Pants","StoreId":1,"Store":null},{"MainMenuId":9,"MenuName":"unixx","StoreId":1,"Store":null},{"MainMenuId":10,"MenuName":"things","StoreId":1,"Store":null}];

var i = 0;

while(i < data.length){

  document.getElementById("mainMenuSelect").innerHTML = document.getElementById("mainMenuSelect").innerHTML + "<option value='"+data[i]["MainMenuId"]+"'>"+data[i]["MenuName"]+"</option>";
  
  i++;

}

</script>
```

Comment: You are always Welcome

Answer (score 0):

your JSON is a string, you need to convert it to javascript object:

```
$.each(JSON.parse(data), function (key, value) {
    $('#mainMenuSelect').append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your data string into a valid json and then parse it to an object.

You also don't really need jQuery to add the options to the select.

```js
var data = '{"MainMenuId":6,"MenuName":"T-Shairt","StoreId":1,"Store":null},{"MainMenuId":7,"MenuName":"Pants","StoreId":1,"Store":null},{"MainMenuId":9,"MenuName":"unixx","StoreId":1,"Store":null},{"MainMenuId":10,"MenuName":"things","StoreId":1,"Store":null}';

var options = JSON.parse('[' + data + ']');
var select = document.getElementById('mainMenuSelect');
options.forEach(function (option, i) {
  select.options[i] = new Option(option.MenuName, option.MainMenuId);
});
```

```html
<select name="mainMenuSelect" id="mainMenuSelect">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is your solution:**

```
var data = [{"MainMenuId":6,"MenuName":"T-Shairt","StoreId":1,"Store":null},{"MainMenuId":7,"MenuName":"Pants","StoreId":1,"Store":null},{"MainMenuId":9,"MenuName":"unixx","StoreId":1,"Store":null},{"MainMenuId":10,"MenuName":"things","StoreId":1,"Store":null}]



$.each(data, function (key, value) {
   $('#mainMenuSelect').append('<option value=' + value.MainMenuId + '>' + value.MenuName + '</option>');
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/721639/)